# Reemplazar , por . al vuelo con javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero que al teclear una , se me cambie por un . en un input que solo acepta números. De momento he conseguido que el input solo acepte números, pero me falta la parte de cambiar la , por un punto Pero estoy un poco Perdido con el tema.

Alguien me podría indicar por donde tirar para hacerlo? he visto codigo que lo hace una vez mandas el formulario, pero yo intento hacerlo al vuelo y no he sido capaz de adaptar codigo para que lo haga como yo necesito.

esto es lo que tengo de momento:

```
function Comprobarnum(e) {
    var numeros = "0123456789,-";  // Variables que definen los caracteres permitidos
    var teclas_especiales = [37, 8, 39, 46, 190, 188, 9, 173]; //46 = Supr, 37 = flecha izquierda, 39 = flecha derecha
    var evento = e || window.event;  // Obtener la tecla pulsada
    var tecla = evento.charCode || evento.keyCode;
    var caracter = String.fromCharCode(tecla);

    var tecla_especial = false; // Comprobar si la tecla pulsada es alguna de las teclas especiales
    for(var i in teclas_especiales) {
        if(tecla == teclas_especiales[i]) { tecla_especial = true; break; }
    }
    var chachi = numeros.indexOf(caracter) != -1 || tecla_especial; // Comprobar si la tecla pulsada se encuentra en los caracteres permitidos
    return chachi;
}
```

Tambien tengo esto, pero no funciona :(

```
function Poner_Punto() {
if(event.keyCode==190) { event.keyCode=188; }
}
```

Comment: `Comprobarnum` se ejecuta en el evento `onKeyUp` o similar? Notas: En vez del `for` puedes usar `indexOf` para evitar hacer bucles. Y en ese metodo, comprueba que pulsa la tecla de la coma y de ser asi, que introduzca un punto y retorne `false`. Un saludo

Comment: ¿Es un `<input type="number"` ? y si no es , ¿Por qué no así ? para  evitar estas validaciones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el evento `keyup` y ademas utilizar `replace`

```js
$('#numero').keyup(function() {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(',', '.'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="numero">
```

Answer (score 2):

Igual te vale esto:

Dado un input en html con id igual a "texto":

```
           <input id="texto" type="text" value="">
```

Capturamos el evento keypress y si la tecla pulsada es la "," (con código which 44), cancelamos los eventos pendientes y en dónde se iba a escribir una ",", ponemos un ".":

```
           <script>
                $("#texto").keypress(function(event) {
                     if(event.which == 44) { // es la coma
                          event.preventDefault();
                          event.target.value += '.';
                     }
                });
           </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ejecuta esto en la funcion de cada pulsación, automáticamente se deberían reemplazar todas las , por . (tras cada pulsación)

```
$('#yourInput').val($('#yourInput').val().split(',').join('.'));
```